# Scroll to specific anchor onload with react

Tags: reactjs, npm, anchor

I have sections with anchors (e.g: `#sources`) and I'm trying to make the page scroll to these sections every time the page's URL with the anchor loads. However this code does not seem to work efficiently and it is very unstable. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

You can see the website in action here: http://f-f-b.surge.sh. To see the bug, just visit the website with this anchor: http://f-f-b.surge.sh/#the-press-of-new-york-its-future. The expected behaviour: the page should scroll constantly to the section where 
`THE PRESS OF NEW YORK-ITS FUTURE` is written.

Here's the code:

In the import:

```
var scrollToElement = require('scroll-to-element');
```

In the state:

```
  this.state = {
  mockDataTweets: _.reverse(mock_data_tweets),
  tweetSamples: null,
  spreadsheetData: null,
  typistIndex: 0,
  about: null,
  whos: null,
  news: null,
  acknowledgments: null,
  windowScroll: 0,
  scrolled: 0,
};
```

In the componentDidMount():

```
componentDidMount(){

  let spreadsheetAPI = config.preFix + config.sheetID + config.postFix;
    axios.get(spreadsheetAPI)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          spreadsheetData: response.data.feed.entry
        })
      }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })

    if(this.state.spreadsheetData === null){
      console.log("unloaded");
    }else{
      console.log("loaded");
      return this.slideLocationPathname()
    }
  }
}
```

Outside of my componentDidMount():

```
  slideLocationPathname = () => {
    let locationPathname = window.location.pathname;
    if(locationPathname !== "/"){
      let pathnameToScroll = "#" + locationPathname.split("/")[1];
      scrollToElement(pathnameToScroll);
    }  
  }
```

Comment: Not sure about your other code, but the if statement in the `slideLocationPathname` function will always be false for the sample link you gave. Thus the `scrollToElement` is never triggered.

Comment: Also you can use `window.location.hash` to get the hash value directly.